# Cancel the affect of first function call with second call of the same function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trim all the input element values on its blur. I defined a function trimElements and called 
in a global page global.js. But in some pages I dont want this feature (trimming); but I already called in global.js. I am trying to nullify the affect of first called function through the second call of same function.
My code is here.

---

### global.js

```
function trimElements(trim) {

if(trim) {
    $("input,textarea").blur(function() {
        $.each($("input"),function() {
            $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()))
        })
    })
}
}

$(document).ready(function(){ 

    trimElements(true);

});
```

---

In some other page I dont want this trim functionality. ie I am trying to do like following

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    trimElements(false); // want to cancel the affect of first function call

});
```

But I am missing some thing in logic.

Comment: What are you missing in the logic?  What's not working?

Comment: When page is loading 2 files global.js and some_other_file.js is loading. in global.js trimElements(true) is called so trim functionality is enabled. Actually I don't want this functionality for some_other_file.js so I called trimElements(false). But it is not working. ie some logical mistake. trim functionality is not disabled ie "not working"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just unbind the element with `false`

```
if(trim) {
...
else {
    $("input,textarea").unbind('blur');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/b9E47/